# regex to find where '&' doesn't have ending semicolon

Tags: python, xml, regex, linux, perl

I have a program that is failing because one of my 10,000 xml files doesn't have a semicolon after the &. And I have no idea which file.

```
The reference to entity "L" must end with the ';' delimiter.
```

Is there a way on the command line (linux) to do a regex search for &L that doesn't end with a semicolon?

Or would a quick script work better?

Comment: By `&L`, do you mean the *exact* two character long string `&L`, or any string of any length that contains the string `&L`?

Comment: `grep "&L[^;]" file`?

Comment: Or maybe, `grep "&[a-zA-Z][^;]" file`?

Comment: @devnull, Even if you add the missing `-P` and `+`, that fails for `'&abc;'` and `'&#x2660;'`.

Answer (score 1):

```
grep --color=auto -P '&[\w#]+(?![\w#;])' *.xml
```

Or if you just want the file names:

```
grep -lP '&[\w#]+(?![\w#;])' *.xml
```